# Limit of n as it approaches infinity of (n/(n+1))?

Tags: limits

I feel like there is something I am missing here. Is this as easy as it looks? Is the limit infinity? Or should I do L'hopital's rule?

With L'hopital I get 1/1 which is just 1.

Comment: I don't get your question. Do you mean limit of $\frac{n}{n+1}$ as $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: @Misakov yes that is what i mean

Comment: @user222031 no that is certainly not me who posted it. thanks for the link tho!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That will work.  You could also to do the following:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\cdot 1/n\over (n+1)\cdot 1/n=}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{1+1/n}=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*

$${ n \over n+1} = 1 - {1 \over n + 1}$$

Now, what's the limit of the right hand side as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Any number of was to skin a cat.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski Exactly. After I wrote this, I was thinking about how many different ways it could be done. I got up to four and then moved on.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it into a middle school word problem and think. The fraction $n/(n+1)$ means $n$ parts of a thing divided into $n+1$ equal parts. Day 1 I eat piece of a pizza that was sliced into two equal parts; on day 2 I eat 2 parts from a pizza sliced into 3 equal parts; on day 99 I would be eating 99 pieces from a pizza sliced into 100 equal parts. Eventually (limit) on a single day how many pizzas would I be eating? Not really a calculus problem needing L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: I feel like this is most like Simon S.'s answer, except with more words and more pizza. Mmm…

Comment: @columbus8myhw:  A learner  who thinks the limit could be infinity and thinks L'Hopital's rule needs to be applied  should be told the problem is much simpler, and pizza is a  way, I thought; if you don't like pizza's you can reformuate that into pancakes, or dosas !

Comment: Hey, no, I'm not saying this is bad in any way; sorry if it came out like that.

Comment: Mm, pizza. The Homer Simpson School of Mathematics.